# How add row in DataGrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I do not understand how to write content from a database to a DataGrid.
Here is the code
Code DataGrid

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" x:Name="ColorsTable" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="DarkGray"
                                        RowBackground="LightGray" AlternatingRowBackground="White" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,0,624.2,0">
                                <DataGrid.Columns>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding Path = Id}" Width="100" />
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path = Name}" Width="100" />
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Specification" Binding="{Binding Path = Specification}" Width="100" />
                                </DataGrid.Columns>
                            </DataGrid>
```

Code add

```
ObservableCollection<SomeAbstact> temp = new ObservableCollection<SomeAbstact>();
            sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [Colors]", SqlConnection);
            reader = await sqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync();
            while (await reader.ReadAsync())
            {
                temp.Add(new Colors()
                {
                    Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Id"]),
                    Name = reader["Name"].ToString(),
                    Specification = reader["Description"].ToString()
                });
            }
            ColorsTable.ItemsSource = temp;
            temp.Clear();
            reader.Close();
```

Entity add

```
public class Colors: SomeAbstact
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Specification { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: try remove  temp.Clear(); and check

Comment: `temp.Clear();`  why are you doing this bro ? you are using this list as `ItemSource` of DataGrid and after assigning you are Clearing the List ? Don't clear the List.

Comment: Also `Binding="{Binding Path = Id}"` instead you can do this `Binding="{Binding Id}"`

Comment: Another thing always check for `Null` when reading data.

Comment: Thank you the problem was temp.Clear()

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the `DataGrid` to the `ObservableCollection` like this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding temp}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Id}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Specification}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

This will only work if the `DataContext` is set properly.
Also you should check out how to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` if you want to use bindings in WPF.